# A minimal maximizing set for a Banach algebra

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a commutative unital Banach Algebra. Let $F$ be a weak*-closed subset of $\Omega(A)$ with the property that for $A$ if for all $x \in A$, $\sup\{ 
|\hat{x}(\phi)| : \phi \in F\} = \rho(x)$, where $\Omega(A)$ is the set of characters in $A$, $\hat{x} $ is the Gelfand Transform, and $\rho$ is the spectral radius.

Show that $A$ admits a minimal set with respect to inclusion amongst all sets with properties of $F$ for $A$. If $A$ is the disk algebra, what is the minimal set as above?

Things I know:

- Since $A$ is a commutative unital Banach Algebra, $\rho(x) = \| \hat{x}\|$.
- If $A$ is the disk algebra then the Gelfand transform is the identity map.

Otherwise I have no clue on how to construct the minimal set.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: I feel like this question is worded badly. I can not make sense of it. Can you try to word it otherwise? An example of bad wording: "if for all $x \in A$" and then the sentence goes nowhere. Also, it is not clear to me what: "Show that A admits a minimal set with respect to inclusion amongst all sets with properties of F for A" means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see that a minimal $F$ exists, we can use Zorn's Lemma. We consider the set of all weak$^*$-closed $F\subset \Omega(A)$ (the unit ball of $A^*$) with reverse inclusion as order. If $\{F_j\}$ is a decreasing chain of sets satisfying
$$
\rho(x)=\sup\{|\hat x(\varphi)|:\ \varphi\in F_j\},\qquad x\in A,
$$
then it has the finite-intersection property. As these sets are weak$^*$-compact,  they have the finite intersection property, so $\displaystyle\bigcap_jF_j\ne\emptyset$. So the chain has an upper bound. By Zorn's Lemma, a minimal $F$ exists.

Knowing that the characters are the point evaluations, and since every function in the disk algebra achieves its extremes on the boundary, the obvious candidate for the minimal set is the boundary.

For every $f\in A(\mathbb D)$, we have that $\sigma(f)=f(\overline{\mathbb D})$. So
$$
\rho(f)=\max\{|f(z)|:\ z\in\overline{\mathbb D}\}=\max\{|f(z)|:\ |z|=1\}. 
$$
The second equality shows that the unit circle $\mathbb T$ satisfies the "F-condition". It remains to show that any proper subset of $\mathbb T$ does not satisfy the condition.

Let $S\subsetneq\mathbb T$ be closed. So there exists $z_0$ with $|z_0|=1$ and $z_0\not\in S$. Let $g:\mathbb T\to\mathbb C$ be given by $g(z)=z_0-z$. Then $\rho(g)=2$. Write $z_0=e^{i\gamma}$. For any $s=e^{i\theta}\in S$,
$$
|g(s)|=|e^{i\gamma}-e^{i\theta}|=|1-e^{i(\theta-\gamma)}|=2(1-\cos(\theta-\gamma)). 
$$
Since $z_0\not\in S$, we get that $|g(s)|<2$ for all $s\in S$. As $S$ is compact, $$\sup\{|g(s)|:\ s\in S\}<2,$$ and so $S$ fails the $F$ property. So indeed $\mathbb T$ is the minimal set.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! For the first part, how do we know that the intersection of all $F$ is not empty?

Comment: I added some more detail.

Comment: What you have is that if $0< \theta,\gamma<2\pi$ then $\cos(\theta-\gamma)=1$ if and only if $\theta=\gamma$.